# How to display all the dates in the date-range having group by dates?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate, count, date

Suppose I have a table called “products”:

```
Productive product-name   product-quantity  created-date
111            ABC          10               1/10/2018
222            XYZ          20               1/10/2018
333            PQR          30               1/11/2018
444            MNC          40               1/15/2018
555            DEF          50               1/11/2018
```

If I run this query:

```
Select convert(date,createddate,101), count(product-quantity) from products
Where created-date > 1/9/2018 and created-date < 1/16/1018
group by convert(date,createddate,101)
```

Which will give me output such as

```
created-date.  product-quantity
1/10/2018            30
1/11/2018            80
1/15/2018            40
```

I want to achieve:

```
created-date.  product-quantity
1/10/2018            30
1/11/2018            80
1/12/2018            00
1/13/2018            00
1/14/2018            00
1/15/2018            40
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You need a calendar table or generate a series of dates.

Comment: An internet search of "calendar table" will return many scripts that show how to create one you can leverage for this and other purposes.

Comment: This one is real handy, and removes the chore of using a tally table or something similar every time you need to use it. Just create it once and be done. It also allows you to skip a lot of date functions which could help performance over a lot of rows. [Aaron Bertrand date dimension / calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic implementation of a Calendar table.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Calendar(cDate datetime, cDay int, cDayOfWeek int, cDayName varchar(20));
>
> DECLARE @date date = '20180101';
> WHILE @date <= '20180131'
> BEGIN
>     INSERT INTO Calendar VALUES (@date, DAY(@date), DATEPART(weekday, @date), DATENAME(weekday, @date));
>     SET @date = DATEADD(day, 1, @date);
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 31 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE products(Productive int, Name char(3), Qty int, Created date);
> INSERT INTO products VALUES
> (111, 'ABC', 10, '1/10/2018'),
> (222, 'XYZ', 20, '1/10/2018'),
> (333, 'PQR', 30, '1/11/2018'),
> (444, 'MNC', 40, '1/15/2018'),
> (555, 'DEF', 50, '1/11/2018');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

Notice I've used a LEFT JOIN to get all records from calendar table and only those records that match on products table.

> ```
> SELECT     c.cDate AS Created, COALESCE(Qty, 0) AS Qty
> FROM       Calendar c
> LEFT JOIN  (SELECT   CONVERT(date, Created, 101) AS [Created],
>                      COUNT(Qty) AS [Qty]
>             FROM     products
>             GROUP BY CONVERT(date, Created, 101)) p
> ON         p.Created = c.cDate
> WHERE      c.cDate >= (SELECT MIN(Created) FROM products)
> AND        c.cDate <= (SELECT MAX(Created) FROM products);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Created             | Qty
> :------------------ | --:
> 10/01/2018 00:00:00 |   2
> 11/01/2018 00:00:00 |   2
> 12/01/2018 00:00:00 |   0
> 13/01/2018 00:00:00 |   0
> 14/01/2018 00:00:00 |   0
> 15/01/2018 00:00:00 |   1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3564e0b73dfec5b239854dde0cfd7622)*